# SQL multiple like

Tags: sql

tengo una tabla con dos campos **CustomerID CustomerName.**

Tengo que encontrar dentro de CustomerName los parametros que yo le pase.

Ejemplo:

```
CustomerID            CustomerName
   3               Antonio Moreno Taquería
   4               Around the Horn
```

La consulta es:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Antonio Taquería%'
```

No me devuelve nada. Como pordia hacer para que me devolviera buscando por Antonio Taquería?

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David, tienes dos opciones.

**1.- reemplazar los espacios por % y pueda coincidir**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Antonio%Taquería%'
```

En este caso te va a coincidir unicamente cuando tengas `Antonio Moreno Taquería`, en caso de tener `Moreno Taquería Antonio`, no va a coincidir.

**2.- Anidar la consulta un AND y aplicar otro LIKE para que busque cada nombre y coincida**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Antonio%' 
AND   CustomerName LIKE '%Taquería%'
```

En este caso sí te va a coincidir en caso de tener en la tabla `Antonio Moreno Taquería` y también `Moreno Taquería Antonio`.

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Hola Jhoubert, primero gracias por l'ayuda. Cuando hago la seguna consulta SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Antonio%' AND CustomerName '%Taquería%' no me funciona me sale este error: Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "'%TaquerÃ­a%'": syntax error)

Comment: Perdona, me falto el LINE de la segúnda condición. edito la respuesta.
 `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Antonio%' AND CustomerName LIKE '%Taquería%'` (respuesta editada también)

Comment: Es importante que quien pregunta ( @David ) entienda que LIKE no separa el contenido entre las comillas ni busca cada palabra por separado. LIKE busca cualquier cosa que contenga lo que se indica entre los símbolos `%` y por eso la sugerencia de Jhoubert funciona.